# Headers messing up on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, html

I have a website where the headers are messing up on iphone, the header tags are rendered using @fontface.

Ive no idea what can be going on as it doesnt happen on the ipod touch nor ipad. What im asking is has anybody had this problem before? could it be a character encoding problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you take that screenshot with a radish? Seriously, though, there's zero useful information to work with here. Do you at least have a link to the site?

Comment: Its pretty hard to get a good screenshot on an iphone.

Comment: You should know better then giving us a low resolution image to work with. Provide some code and preferably a link to the website.

Comment: I've created a thread on the official support forums. It would be nice, if you add your "i have this too" there :) https://discussions.apple.com/message/16655075#16655075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same issue with my iPod Touch 3G running iOS 5. It's not reproduceable, after closing a website and it only happens when I start zooming. I'd say it's a bug in iOS5. Never had this before on earlier releases.

Comment: Thanks Sn0opy, Ive noticed its also an iO5 issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a conditional stylesheet to replace any  tags with web standard fonts which has worked, the problem now is my background is being replaced as a tiled button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for opening an old question, but I just had a header issue with my site, turns out some mobile browsers give header tags a bold font-weight, so if you can't give a bold style with your custom font you have to set the header tags (h1, h2....) to `font-weight:normal;` or `font-weight:400;` and it fixes the issues.